# non-instantiated constructor functions in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I know I can create a constructor with constructor functions like

```
var obj = function() {this.fun1 = function(){...};};
```

and then add functions to the constructor with

```
obj.prototype.fun2 = function(){...}; //etc...
```

My question is, is it possible to declare functions within an object that can be called without instantiating an object. To understand what I mean, take the Array object. you can declare an array like

```
var arr = [...];
```

and the call functions on that array like

```
arr.length();
```

Such functions are of the format

```
Array.prototype.length = function() {...}
```

But there are other functions that are not a part of the prototype that can be called without instantiating an Array, such as `Array.isArray()` (which is distinctly *not* `Array.prototype.isArray()`). Is there a way to declare similar functions in custom constructors?

Comment: It's called a "static method".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about the difference between [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) and non-static methods.

A static method does not require an instance of a class, but instead is called on the constructor itself. Because functions are objects, you can just assign properties and methods to the constructor function:

```
const MyClass = function () {
  // this is a constructor function
};

MyClass.staticProperty = 'foo';

MyClass.staticMethod = function () {
  // this is a static method
};

MyClass.prototype.method = function () {
  // this is a non-static method
};
```

In order to call `staticMethod`, you do not need to create an instance of `MyClass` — just call it:

```
MyClass.staticMethod();
```

In order to call `method`, you *do* need to create an instance of `MyClass`:

```
const obj = new MyClass();
obj.method();
```

Using the ES2015 class syntax, you can define a static method with the help of the `static` keyword:

```
class MyClass ()
  constructor () {
    // ...
  }
  static staticMethod () {
    // ...
  }
}
MyClass.staticMethod(); // call the static method
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object lilteral and add functions as properties, or create a constructor function and then add the methods to the constructor function.

```js
var myObject = {
  myAlert: function(str) {
    alert(str);
  }
};
myObject.myAlert('Hello');

var MyConstructor = function() {
};
MyConstructor.myAlert = function(str) {
  alert(str);
}
MyConstructor.myAlert('Bye');
```

The following however will not work, because you cannot access the `myAlert`  method without instantiating the constructor function, and creating an object.

```
var MyOtherConstructor = function() {
  this.myAlert = function(str) {
    alert(str);
  }
};
MyOtherConstructor.myAlert('FAIL');
```

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly you can define a `static` method at a `class`

```js
class C {
  static method() {
    return 123
  }
}

console.log(C.method());
```